# importing 3rd party libraries into app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Im having trouble getting app engine to accept a 3rd party library.

ive copied it into the the app engine directory, but i keep getting the error, "invalid object, the library tweepy is not supported" in blah blah blah/app.yaml

could somebody point out the obvious mistake please?

thanks

ok, ive made a few changes to the code and now i get this error, hopefully it is more useful

```
 2012-10-15 20:09:36 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program             Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8083', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\ladds\\My Documents\\udacity\\whycantisigh']"
```

WARNING  2012-10-15 19:09:54,140 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
WARNING  2012-10-15 19:09:56,171 datastore_file_stub.py:513] Could not read datastore data from c:\docume~1\ladds\locals~1\temp\dev_appserver.datastore
WARNING  2012-10-15 19:09:56,203 dev_appserver.py:3394] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
INFO     2012-10-15 19:09:56,328 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:647] Running application dev~whycantisigh on port 8083: #http://localhost:8083
INFO     2012-10-15 19:09:56,328 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:649] Admin console is available at: #http://localhost:8083/_ah/admin
WARNING  2012-10-15 19:10:26,171 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2-1.0.2-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2-1.0.2-py2.7.egg'
WARNING  2012-10-15 19:10:26,171 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ply-3.4-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ply-3.4-py2.7.egg'
WARNING  2012-10-15 19:10:26,187 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy-1.11-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy-1.11-py2.7.egg'
INFO     2012-10-15 19:10:30,171 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
INFO     2012-10-15 19:18:04,250 py_zipimport.py:148] zipimporter('C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', '')
INFO     2012-10-15 19:18:04,250 py_zipimport.py:148] zipimporter('C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ply-3.4-py2.7.egg', '')
INFO     2012-10-15 19:18:04,250 py_zipimport.py:148] zipimporter('C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy-1.11-py2.7.egg', '')
INFO     2012-10-15 19:18:06,640 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 -

im sorry its not formatted clearly, but it will only let me format the first line.

anyway, the gist of the problem seems to be that 3rd party libraries i have downloaded into python(and that work in the shell) arent accessible by app engine.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/libraries

> Many Native C Python modules are disabled with Google App Engine. The Python 2.7 runtime supports more modules than the Python 2.5 runtime.

Comment: im using 2.7, and the library im trying to use - tweepy - is pure python.

Comment: as per the other answer, you need to add more information if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed your app.yaml and the actual error message instead of blah blah blah.

But most likely you put tweepy in app.yaml and you don't need to.

**Edit**

To use 3rd party libraries with GAE, you need to put a copy of the library in your project folder.  Otherwise, it won't get uploaded to the server on deploy.  Installing it to your python path won't work.

Comment: sorry, blah blah blah was just the path but that is the actual error message.

Comment: ive addded the error code that i get,  but it seems like a bigger problem than just where to put the 3rd party libraries, as now none of the apps that i have been working on will work and they all generate the same error message as i have added above. including the ones in a completely seperate app that i have never tried to use a 3rd party library in.